# Core-js: Module not found for object.keys

Tags: angular, core-js, ngx-toastr

In order to fix the ngx-toaster issue in IE https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues/673
I need the following import error in my pollyfills.ts

`import 'core-js/features/object/keys'`

I am getting Module not found  error

Does anyone know the equivalent import of the above in core-js version `2.5.4`

Answer (score 0):

I use version 2.6.5 and import it like so:

```
import 'core-js/es6/object';
```

This should work for you too.